# PostgreSQL and Hibernate give different results for same date_part query

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, datepart

When I try to find the elapsed time for different jobs, I recieve negative values in my Spring Boot App, while I receive expected results from the psql cli.

This is the Hibernate query, using the exact same query as I created in psql.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT bind_name, type_name, max((24 * 60 * date_part('day', current_timestamp - created)) + (60 * date_part('hour', current_timestamp - created)) + (date_part('minute', current_timestamp - created))) FROM job WHERE state IN ('INITIAL', 'SUBMITTED') AND bind_name IS NOT NULL AND  type_name IS NOT NULL GROUP BY bind_name, type_name", nativeQuery = true)
```

For additional information, the job says -180 minutes have passed when I start a new job. I thought (more so hoped) because I was working in on the west coast this past week, that would have been the culprit, but it seems to persist. Has anyone ran into a problem like this? I haven't seen the issue reported anywhere else. I also tried to change the query to the `extract` method but got the same issue.

Comment: Unrelated, but: if you want to convert an `interval` to minutes, this can be done much shorter using `extact(epoch from current_timestamp - created) / 60`

Comment: How does your table look like? And how does your method look like?

Comment: Please post examples, as text - **no images**,  of what you get from your app and from psql. Is there a timezone difference between your  Hibernate environment and the DB Server?